# Why does recode_factor not allow to drop levels?

Tags: r, dplyr

I like `recode_factor` from `dplyr` because it lets you (1) recode factor levels and (2) order them at the same time. I also like how it lets you (3) drop levels when you turn a numeric vector into a factor vector. For example:

```
num_vec <- c(1:4, NA)

recode_factor(num_vec, `1` = "z", `2` = "y", `3` = "x", .ordered = TRUE,)
[1] z    y    x    <NA> <NA>
Levels: z < y < x
```

Note how the value `4`, which is not recoded, turns into `NA` because it is interpreted as "incompatible". For me, this behavior is practical. Unfortunately, the same is not possible for character vectors (because they are interpreted as compatible):

```
chr_vec <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", NA)

recode_factor(chr_vec, `a` = "z", `b` = "y", `c` = "x", .ordered = TRUE,)
[1] z    y    x    d    <NA>
Levels: z < y < x < d
```

Note that instead of turning into `NA`, `d` remains itself.

Is there any way around this latter behavior - with equally short code? I am aware of the usual `factor` method with `levels` specified, but to my knowledge doing (1) recoding of levels (2) ordering them (3) turning some levels into `NA` requires more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `.default` argument in [`recode_factor`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/recode.html) (see the third example in the help file):

```
recode_factor(chr_vec, `a` = "z", `b` = "y", `c` = "x", 
             .ordered = TRUE, 
             .default = NA_character_)

# [1] z    y    x    <NA> <NA>
# Levels: z < y < x
```

The `.default` argument:

> If supplied, all values not otherwise matched will be given this value. If not supplied and if the replacements are the same type as the original values in .x, unmatched values are not changed. If not supplied and if the replacements are not compatible, unmatched values are replaced with NA.

Comment: Great - I was aware of the `.default` argument, but the use of `NA_character_` is new to me!